# isequal not returning true for element in cell array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, comparison, cell-array, comparison-operators

any idea why this isn't returning true???

comments01a is a cell array of cells although I'd be perfectly happy converting it to a matrix. However, cell2mat(comments01a) gives its own error that it doesn't support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects (which this one does) and I don't know of any alternatives.

> > comments01a{1}

ans =
'4'

> > isequal(comments01a{1}, '4')

ans =
0

Answer (score 2):

Because '4', in this case, is a cell containing the string '4'. So, isequal is comparing a cell to a string. The solution is either this:

```
strcmp(comments01a{1}, '4')
```

Or maybe this, if you've actually nested cells in cells, as your question suggests:

```
strcmp(comments01a{1}{1}, '4')
```

If neither of these do it, you can try this, which replaces the '4' string with the number:

```
isequal(comments01a{1}{1}, 4)
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if it doesn't, and I'll take another shot at it.